# Firebird errors when using Symmetricds

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, symmetricds

I am using symmetricds free version to replicate my firebird database. When I demo by creating new (blank) DB, it worked fine. But when I config on my existing DB (have data), error occurred.

[image]

I use Firebird-2.5.5.26952_0 32bit & symmetric-server-3.9.5, OS is Windows Server 2008 Enterprise.

I had searched for whole day but found nothing to solve this. Anyone please help. Thank for your time.

**UPDATE:**
When initial load, Symmetric execute the statement to declare UDF in firebird DB:

```
declare external function sym_hex blob   
  returns cstring(32660) free_it 
  entry_point 'sym_hex' module_name 'sym_udf
```

It caused error because my existing DB charset is `UNICODE_FSS`, max length of CSTRING is 10922. When I work around by updating charset to `NONE`, it worked fine. But it is not a safe solution. Still working to find better.

One more thing, anyone know others open source tool to replicate Firebird database, I tried many in [here](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq249/) and only Symmetric work.

Comment: There's an open bug in the issue tracker: https://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2369 :/

Comment: Could you lower the logging level to DEBUG and get the sql statement that is throwing the exception?

Comment: @BorisPavlović  what do you mean "lower the logging level to DEBUG"? I saw this issue when searching for solution, seem like nobody can fix it :)

Comment: Using a free version means that if there's a problem you'll have to find a way how to go around it. Rename the file `SYMMETRIC_DS_HOME\conf\log4j.xml` to  `SYMMETRIC_DS_HOME\conf\log4j.xml_backup` and the file `SYMMETRIC_DS_HOME\conf\log4j-debug.xml` to `SYMMETRIC_DS_HOME\conf\log4j.xml`. Restart the engine to get the logs with the sql that is failing. The log can be found in `SYMMETRIC_DS_HOME\log\`

Comment: thanks @BorisPavlović. I follow your steps and update the picture of log file above, still not see which sql statement caused the error.

Comment: there should be log statements with `org.jumpmind.symmetric.io` classes which print out the sql statements

Comment: Could you copy/paste the exact exception?

Comment: Please post errors, logging and code as **text**, not as screenshots.

Comment: "How can I increase the *implementation limit* of cstring length of my DB?" - by rewriting the implementation (which is the Firebird itself). So, that is hardly what you practically can do. I wonder if FB3 and UDR interface could provide for longer-buffer function instead.

Comment: Now, looking at http://freeadhocudf.org/documentation_english/dok_eng_blob.html I see that the library worked with 32760 > 32660 CSTRING size. Can it be that CSTRING is affected by either connection or database default charset ?

Comment: FB SQL LangRef claims that CSTRNIg limit is in BYTES not CHARs anyway

Comment: It may happen that Database default language is affecting CSTRING datatype interpretation, at least judging by `strlen` declaration in `c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\UDF\ib_udf2.sql` (but not in `ib_udf.sql`).  So, @Jacky, please issue this command on BOTH old and new databases: `SELECT RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM RDB$DATABASE`

Comment: As of now I expect the old database be using some 1-byte MBCS (probably `WIN1250` or `WIN1252`) and the new database some Unicode flavor... Which would make all old text-based UDFs potentially returning wrong data (mismatching new DB charset), unless you mend all them UDF declarations to explicitly state every text parameter, input or output, with the charset as in the old database

Comment: Seems you have unicode database, which cannot have such long cstring as returning cos firebird unicode varchar is only 32,767/4

Comment: ....which, if so, begs a question why Symmetrics does not apreciate this crucial setting. It is a good luck, if so, that his function was so long-resulted, it crashed explicitly on the declaration step. It would be much worse if it went under radar without early explicit errors....

Comment: UNICODE_FSS is outdated and shaky. NONE is plain dangerous. At this time I suggest you look into CHAR/VARCHAR/BLOB subtype text fields in your database to see if those columns have any charset attributed. If not - you come into very dangerous water. At very least Symmetics seems to fail clone database charset. Maybe it is by design, maybe it explicitly recreates charsets of columns and udf arguments instead. You have to check it.  //// did you tried most recent Firebird 2.5.8 ?

Comment: check the UDF in the old database, if her parameters are tagged with character sets, probably both of them are UNICODE_FSS there in old DB and maybe you can fix the function definition for new DB by specifying charsets for both parameters explicitly. That said, you better consult the UDF developer to learn which characters sets those parameters must be.

Comment: what is the Connection Charset as u specify in IBExpert database registration info window? Or `SELECT RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME
 FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS, RDB$CHARACTER_SETS WHERE MON$CHARACTER_SET_ID = RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID`

Comment: 1) please DO put all the requests and errors into your questions AS TEXT. Screenshots are both hard to reuse and will be expired and removed in indeterminate short timespan. 2) please put your additional data you mentioned in comments into the question text also. No one like reading long commentwalls for crumbs of data. 3) link this discussion along with crucial data into the bug report you opened on Symmetrics, otherwise if Symmetrics team would ever look into it - they would never know those extra details.

Comment: @Arioch'The thank you for the instruction, I updated my question and deleted some comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a bug in Firebird where the length of `CSTRING` is supposed to be in bytes, but in reality it uses characters. Your database seems to have `UTF8` (or `UNICODE_FSS`) as its default character set, which means each character can take up to 4 bytes (3 for `UNICODE_FSS`). The maximum length of `CSTRING` is 32767 bytes, but if it calculates in characters for `CSTRING`, that suddenly reduces the maximum to 8191 characters (or 32764 bytes) (or 10922 characters, 32766 bytes for `UNICODE_FSS`).

The workaround to this problem would be to create a database with a different default character set. Alternatively, you could (temporarily) alter the default character set:

For Firebird 3:

1. Set the default character set to a single byte character set (eg `NONE`). **Use of `NONE` is preferable to avoid unintended transliteration issues**

   ```
   alter database set default character set NONE;
   ```
2. Disconnect (important, you may need to disconnect all current connections because of metadata caching!)
3. Set up SymmetricDS so it creates the UDF
4. Set the default character set back to `UTF8` (or `UNICODE_FSS`)

   ```
   alter database set default character set UTF8;
   ```
5. Disconnect again

When using Firebird 2.5 or earlier, you will need perform a direct system table update (which is no longer possible in Firebird 3) using:

Step 2:

```
update RDB$DATABASE set RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'NONE'
```

Step 4:

```
update RDB$DATABASE set RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'UTF8'
```

The alternative would be for SymmetricDS to change its initialization to

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION SYM_HEX
    BLOB
    RETURNS CSTRING(32660) CHARACTER SET NONE FREE_IT
    ENTRY_POINT 'sym_hex' MODULE_NAME 'sym_udf';
```

Or maybe character set `BINARY` instead of `NONE`, as that seems closer to the intent of the UDF.

Comment: See his comments, Mark. He claims his new database has NONE charset not his old one. Sounds weird...

Comment: @Arioch'The I had missed that comment. But, they say it works with a new blank database, not with the existing database, and that matches with this answer and the character set they mention for each.

Comment: @Arioch'The when I create new blank DB to test, I do not set the charset, leave it as default value (NONE). The old DB was created by someone long time before, and use charset `UNICODE_FSS`, our DB has too much unicode data, now I have to replicate this old DB :)

Comment: @Jacky The default character set only specifies the character set to use when you add (create) a new column without specifying an explicit character set.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  anyway, thanks for `update RDB$DATABASE set RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'NONE'` statement, stopped at step 3 and it worked fine. When I update charset back to `UNICODE_FSS` (step 4), symmetric stop working.

Comment: @Jacky I don't use SymmetricDS myself, so I don't know what else I can do to help you. You might want to check if there is some type of support forum or mailing list for SymmetricDS and see if you can find more help there.

Comment: what is "sym_udf" library? who developed it, you? Cause the command in your IBExpert is lacking character set, and that is dangerous, code smell! You just demonstrated why so - because then the correctness of the function becomes **implicitly** dependent upon outer context (database defaults)

Comment: @Arioch'The It is part of [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/), and technically CSTRING shouldn't have a character set (but for some reason it appears Firebird applies character set semantics).

Comment: `CSTRING shouldn't have a character set` this is a quite questionable interpretation. How would you transcode then `select udf(1) frin rdb$database` to connection charset ? However documentation seriously fails here, that is for sure.

Comment: `It is part of SymmetricDS` - the name hints at that but I am not sure if it is so officially, and don't want to dig into it too much. But if it is so, then the bug should be pinned to Symmetrics on wrong function declaration

Comment: Just for the record, discussion about UDF documentation and implementation (in Russian) : http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=1228946&msg=21295927 and http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=1123374&msg=21295896

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm sure about it being part of SymmetricDS, I checked their source code. And CSTRING is supposed to be in bytes, it specifically says so in the Firebird and InterBase documentation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I told about this aspect of docs back on March 29. But it seems like the bug in documentation.